# Can non-rectangular windows which scroll diagonally be created on a webpage?

Tags: scrolling

Can non-rectangular windows with scrolling-bars to scroll diagonally or even in an arc be fitted into a webpage?

I have never seen an example of this, but I think it might make internet browsing more interesting.